# How do I create an ActiveRecord scaffold after installing mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every time I run `rails g scaffold ModelName` a mongoid model migration is created. I would like to create an ActiveRecord scaffold though. How do I do this?

```
rails g active_record:scaffold ModelName
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have config.generators configured in your application.rb file?

I use MongoMapper a lot, and I add :

config.generators do |g|
g.orm :mongo_mapper
end

into application.rb to ensure that all my generators do things the MongoMapper way - if you have something like that in your application.rb file, or somehow set it statically somewhere this may be the reason that you're getting this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveRecord generators are still available, you just need to specify to use the 'active_record' versions as you use them.

For example, at this point 'rails g model user email' generates a Mongoid model but 'rails g active_record:model user email' generates an ActiveRecord model and creates the needed migration.

If you chose to make this a Mongoid model, there is no migration to worry about. If you chose to make this an ActiveRecord model, run the migration with 'rails db:migrate'. (Rails 5 moved rake functionality into the rails command)